# How to Setup IntelliJ IDEA So That a Multi-Module Maven Project Can Be Stored As Individual Git Repos But "Imported" Into the IntelliJ Project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, intellij-idea

I am attempting to set up IntelliJ IDEA on my local machine.  I am trying to incorporate a multi-module maven project into IntelliJ IDEA (aka IJ). The maven project is contained in a remote git cloud service (ie: github, gitlab, etc).

My current set up is using Eclipse instead of IJ.  I work a bit unorthodox, in that I have my cloned repos sitting outside of my Eclipse workspace.  In Eclipse I just import the repos into my workspace.  I find that this saves me headaches when I try to maintain the repos, so that my workspace is basically unaffected.  I want to try and reproduce this approach, but for IJ.

However, when I tried to mimic this approach but for IJ, I get errors in the source code, for instance "Symbol String not Found" error when the code does something simple like declare a variable of type String.

Here was my approach:

1. Welcome screen, pick "Open", navigate to a folder that I have created to be my IJ project "intellij-projects".
2. IJ opens, and in the Project Tool Window I see a module named after the project "intellij-projects".
3. I do File > New > "Module From Existing Sources" for a multi-module maven project named "glass-parent".  I follow the wizard and select my relevant external git repo.
4. The module "glass-parent" is created.  I can open the module in the Project Tool Window to reveal sub-modules "glass-app" and "glass-second-app".
5. I do File > New > "Module From Existing Sources" for a multi-module maven project named "vessel-parent".  I follow the wizard and select my relevant external git repo.
6. The module "vessel-parent" is created.  I can open the module in the Project Tool Window to reveal sub-modules "vessel-app", "vessel-second-app", "vessel-third-app".

So now I have 3 modules in the Project Tool Window, with 2 of them parent modules that contain sub-modules, and 1 is just the IJ project.  However, like I said there are errors.

My colleague said that he prefers to have the project contain the git repos.  He directed me to do this and using his approach, I was able to get the project setup, but now without errors.  In addition, there is no third module listed in the Project Tool Window with a name that matches the folder that I placed this project in.  I can describe what was done if requested but my current focus is on instead keeping repos external to the project folder, using some variation on my approach instead of my colleague's approach.

My question: is there a way to setup IJ to work like I have setup my Eclipse - import the external git repo modules into my project, instead of having the repos colocated with the project?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?